# Converting TIN to Multipolygon in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon, convert, tin, tesselation

`ST_Tesselate` returns `TIN` geometry. But then I need to use other software to process geometry data and it only accept (multi-)linestrings and (multi-)polygons.

Is there way to convert `TIN` triangles to multipolygon?

`TIN` is 2-dimentional, no Z coordinate.

Comment: Without knowing your source data, could you perhaps use http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DelaunayTriangles.html instead?

Comment: No, `ST_DelaunayTriangles` collects all points and creates convex surface and trianglates it as shown on illustration on that page you provided link to. I don't need creating convex polygon, I just need trianglate existing multipolygons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ST_Dump`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) to extract individual `TRIANGLE` elements from the `TIN`.  Then, you can convert an individual `TRIANGLE` to a `POLYGON` using [`ST_ExteriorRing`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html) and [`ST_MakePolygon`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html).  If you then need to combine these polygons into a single `MULTIPOLYGON`, you could use [`ST_Collect`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html).  Putting that all together would look like this:

```
WITH test_geom AS (SELECT 'POLYGON (( 10 190, 10 70, 80 70, 80 130, 50 160, 120 160, 120 190, 10 190 ))'::geometry AS geom)

SELECT ST_Collect(geom) AS geom 
FROM (
  SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(ST_Tesselate(geom))).geom)) AS geom 
  FROM test_geom) sq;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Many thanks. I've covered this code with a function for easy "tesselation into multipolygons": https://gist.github.com/romanshuvalov/8ac44a84c365e31cf049245c8a4852d7