# Saving a TIN given as a Wavefront OBJ file into PostGIS internal TIN format

Tags: postgis, tin, mesh, ply, obj

I was given a [TIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_irregular_network) representing a terrain as an [OBJ file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file):

[image: The obj terrain]

I need to store it into a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database as the PostGIS [internal `TIN` format](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/3d.html).

How could I do that?

If needed I can have access to the original raster DEM as a GeoTIFF file.

For convenience, I've tried to load the OBJ file into [QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html) but no luck; this format is not recognized as a valid mesh or vector format:

> Invalid Data Source: /data/TIN/dem.obj is not a valid or recognized data source.

Apparently, QGIS only seems to rely on those mesh file formats: https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL#supported-formats

So I converted the OBJ to the [Stanford PLY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) file format, and I succeeded to load it:

[image: The PLY mesh in QGIS]

But then, how could I save it to the PostGIS database?

Note: at the really end, the machine I will have to execute this process is a headless Linux server (Ubuntu 20.04), so it would ideally have to be run only at the command line on such environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a DIY solution, after diving into the galaxy of 3D related stuff, I found a nice Python (>= 3.7) [MIT licensed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) package called [meshio](https://pypi.org/project/meshio/) (*Schlömer, Nico. (2022). meshio: Tools for mesh files (v5.3.4). Zenodo. https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.6346837*) ([github](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio)) which can translate between some 3D formats. Upon those, luckily `WKT`. This package can be installed on Ubuntu either with:

- `pip install meshio` or
- `apt-get install meshio-tools`

Then, simply from a bash prompt:

```sh
$ meshio --version
meshio 5.3.4 [Python 3.10.4]
Copyright (c) 2015-2021 Nico Schlömer et al.

$ meshio convert input.obj output.wkt
```

After what, one can load this WKT file to PostGIS from a `psql` CLI.
But this is the tricky part which I cannot yet fully automate because of the `\set` statement:

```sql
\set content `cat /path/to/output.wkt`
UPDATE table SET wkt_geom = :'content' WHERE id=1;
```

Or by simply copy/pasting the raw content of the file in a prepared query (beware, this can be laggy with large content...).

Finally, one can visualize the result, e.g. in pgAdmin, using such query (inspired by: [Converting TIN to Multipolygon in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209825/converting-tin-to-multipolygon-in-postgis)):

```sql
SELECT
  ST_Force2d(ST_Transform(ST_Collect(geom), 4326)) AS geom 
FROM (
  SELECT
    ST_MakePolygon(
      ST_ExteriorRing(
        (ST_Dump(wkt_geom)).geom
      )
    ) AS geom
  FROM table
  WHERE id=1
) foo;
```

Which results in:

[image: Result in pgAdmin]

(If you have an FME license, you can probably do the same using an OBJ reader or a Triangulator up to the PostGIS writer, but I didn't try).

⚠️ **Drawback:**

This goes well when playing with small data sets (up to a few triangles) but for large data sets it's definitely not optimal and you may run into critical issues, see: [Storing a large 3D TIN into a PostGIS database](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429999/storing-a-large-3d-tin-into-a-postgis-database)
Therefore, you'd better split your input data into sub chunks.

Comment: I just installed meshio, but get "meshio: command not found" when running it from a terminal. Seems to be nothing findable to fix this.