# Storing a large 3D TIN into a PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, tin, mesh, postgresql-14

I have to store a *massive* TIN (1.5 GB) into a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database to do some computations with it.

[image: A massive TIN]

After my first try, I was getting a "server closed the connection unexpectedly" issue when trying to insert such massive 3D TIN data set as a *single* record into a PostGIS database:

```sql
mydatabase=# \set content `cat /path/to/massive/dem.wkt`
mydatabase=# UPDATE mytable SET tin = :'content' WHERE id=1;
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
psql (14.2 (Ubuntu 14.2-1ubuntu1), server 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1))
mydatabase=#
```

But then, I was quickly told that a single PostgreSQL record can "only" hold 1 GB of data: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html + that probably my design was badly thought. But I need to compute a 3D intersection between that TIN and a 3D Polygon which is already in the database.

Therefore, I'm now asking myself what would be the best strategy to store a 3D TIN (covering a large region, up to a country size: ~5'000'000 triangles) in a PostGIS database?

More specifically -- but this may also be a nonsense in the opposite way as storing the entire object as a single record; I don't know -- how to store each and every triangle of a TIN as a single record in a PostGIS table (that I will be able to actually index, if possible)?

Or maybe something in between; using mini-batches of (tiled?) data (then, what could be the optimal size and how to compute it)?

The TIN may be given as a mesh file ([PLY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) or [OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) file format) or as a [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) string inside a file:

```
TIN Z (((7.58 45.34 532.1, 7.58 47.33 504.7, 7.59 47.31 564.8, 7.58 47.34 532.1)),((...
```

[This query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/209845/65370) could have helped if the TIN was already in the database, but it's not the case, simply because I cannot insert it because of its size on the disk.

After a while, I'm more and more thinking, in a way, that's it's a mesh splitting problem.
In case I'd like sub-parts composed of more than one triangle element, it's <strike>probably</strike> certainly not trivial, but for simple individual elements, it should be easy... I guess.

And as far as I know, mesh edition is [not yet implemented in QGIS.](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/228)

I seek a command line solution using open source tools.

**Info:**

postgresql version();
`"PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit"`

postgis_full_version();
`"POSTGIS=""3.1.4 ded6c34"" [EXTENSION] PGSQL=""140"" GEOS=""3.9.0-CAPI-1.16.2"" SFCGAL=""1.3.8"" PROJ=""7.2.1"" LIBXML=""2.9.10"" LIBJSON=""0.15"" LIBPROTOBUF=""1.3.3"" WAGYU=""0.5.0 (Internal)"" TOPOLOGY"`

postgis_sfcgal_version();
`"1.3.8"`

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 64 bits.