# Speeding up a TIN to MultiPolygonZ conversion in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, convert, tin, tesselation

I have a TIN record in a PostGIS database. It contains between 50'000 and 100'000 triangles:

[image: TIN terrain with many triangles]

Based on this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/209845/65370 I'm trying for the moment to dump the triangles to a `MultiPolygonZ`, but this query has now run for <strike>4h</strike> <strike>8h</strike> >24h and it is not over yet:

```sql
SELECT ST_Transform(ST_Collect(geom), 4326) AS geom 
FROM (
  SELECT
    ST_MakePolygon(
      ST_ExteriorRing(
        (ST_Dump(ST_Tesselate(tin))).geom
      )
    ) AS geom
  FROM mytable WHERE id=1
) sq;
```

Is there something I can do to accelerate things?
I cannot figure out if it's possible to build an index on a TIN column for example.

**Info:**

postgresql version();
`"PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit"`

postgis_full_version();
`"POSTGIS=""3.1.4 ded6c34"" [EXTENSION] PGSQL=""140"" GEOS=""3.9.0-CAPI-1.16.2"" SFCGAL=""1.3.8"" PROJ=""7.2.1"" LIBXML=""2.9.10"" LIBJSON=""0.15"" LIBPROTOBUF=""1.3.3"" WAGYU=""0.5.0 (Internal)"" TOPOLOGY"`

postgis_sfcgal_version();
`"1.3.8"`

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 64 bits.

Comment: Hi, I've never used the Tin management functions of PostGis, but it seems that the query doesn't do exactly what you want. It starts by building a TIN (```ST_Tesselate```) before dumping when you indicate you already have a Tin. In my opinion you just need to dump the Tin. This is explained in the examples in the [PostGIS documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) (cf. last example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atm was actually right in his comment. And indeed, it's actually a nonsense to tessellate a TIN!
It was an error on my side.

Here is a detailed comparison for a same query with and without the use of [`ST_Tesselate()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Tesselate.html).

I ticked all the options within pgAdmin4 (6.8.0) before running `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` in both cases:

[image: selected options of "EXPLAIN ANALYSE" within pgadmin4]

The original query, which is not the one shown here as an example and which wasn't terminated after 48h with the usage of `ST_Tesselate()` only took ~400ms to finish without `ST_Tesselate()`.

#### Query plan execution analysis (`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) with `ST_Tesselate()`

##### Executed query

```
SELECT (ST_Transform(ST_Collect(geom), 4326)) AS geom 
FROM (
  SELECT
    ST_MakePolygon(
      ST_ExteriorRing(
        (ST_Dump(ST_Tesselate(tin))).geom
      )
    ) AS geom
  FROM mytable WHERE id=1
) sq;
```

##### Raw results

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Aggregate",
      "Strategy": "Plain",
      "Partial Mode": "Simple",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Async Capable": false,
      "Startup Cost": 49184.77,
      "Total Cost": 49209.78,
      "Plan Rows": 1,
      "Plan Width": 32,
      "Actual Startup Time": 2214.623,
      "Actual Total Time": 2214.624,
      "Actual Rows": 1,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Output": [
        "st_transform(
           st_collect(
             (st_makepolygon(
               st_exteriorring(
                 ((st_dump(st_tesselate(mytable.tin)))).geom
               )
             )
           )
         ),
         4326)"
      ],
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 15617,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 29296,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Result",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Async Capable": false,
          "Startup Cost": 0,
          "Total Cost": 49183.38,
          "Plan Rows": 1000,
          "Plan Width": 32,
          "Actual Startup Time": 2145.842,
          "Actual Total Time": 2213.024,
          "Actual Rows": 297,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Output": [
            "st_makepolygon(
               st_exteriorring(
                 ((st_dump(st_tesselate(mytable.tin)))).geom
               )
             )"
          ],
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 15617,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 29296,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "ProjectSet",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Startup Cost": 0,
              "Total Cost": 47423.38,
              "Plan Rows": 1000,
              "Plan Width": 32,
              "Actual Startup Time": 2145.835,
              "Actual Total Time": 2212.838,
              "Actual Rows": 297,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Output": [
                "st_dump(st_tesselate(mytable.tin))"
              ],
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 15617,
              "Shared Read Blocks": 29296,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Async Capable": false,
                  "Relation Name": "mytable",
                  "Schema": "public",
                  "Alias": "mytable",
                  "Startup Cost": 0,
                  "Total Cost": 47416.88,
                  "Plan Rows": 1,
                  "Plan Width": 30928,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 3.761,
                  "Actual Total Time": 70.397,
                  "Actual Rows": 1,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Output": [
                    "mytable.tin"
                  ],
                  "Filter": "(mytable.id = 1 )",
                  "Rows Removed by Filter": 200428,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 15612,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 29296,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Settings": {
      "search_path": "\"$user\", public, topology"
    },
    "Planning": {
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0
    },
    "Planning Time": 0.062,
    "Triggers": [],
    "Execution Time": 2214.655
  }
]
```

##### Visual results

[image: visual results with st_tesselate]

#### Query plan execution analysis (`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) without `ST_Tesselate()`:

##### Executed query

```
SELECT (ST_Transform(ST_Collect(geom), 4326)) AS geom 
FROM (
  SELECT
    ST_MakePolygon(
      ST_ExteriorRing(
        (ST_Dump((tin))).geom
      )
    ) AS geom
  FROM mytable WHERE id=1
) sq;
```

##### Raw results

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Aggregate",
      "Strategy": "Plain",
      "Partial Mode": "Simple",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Async Capable": false,
      "Startup Cost": 48934.52,
      "Total Cost": 48959.53,
      "Plan Rows": 1,
      "Plan Width": 32,
      "Actual Startup Time": 60.759,
      "Actual Total Time": 60.76,
      "Actual Rows": 1,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Output": [
        "st_transform(
           st_collect(
             (st_makepolygon(
               st_exteriorring(
                 ((st_dump(mytable.tin))).geom
               )
             ))
           ),
           4326)"
      ],
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 16160,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 28753,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Result",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Async Capable": false,
          "Startup Cost": 0,
          "Total Cost": 48933.13,
          "Plan Rows": 1000,
          "Plan Width": 32,
          "Actual Startup Time": 4.005,
          "Actual Total Time": 59.691,
          "Actual Rows": 297,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Output": [
            "st_makepolygon(
               st_exteriorring(
                 ((st_dump(mytable.tin))).geom
               )
            )"
          ],
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 16160,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 28753,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "ProjectSet",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Startup Cost": 0,
              "Total Cost": 47423.13,
              "Plan Rows": 1000,
              "Plan Width": 32,
              "Actual Startup Time": 4,
              "Actual Total Time": 59.553,
              "Actual Rows": 297,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Output": [
                "st_dump(mytable.tin)"
              ],
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 16160,
              "Shared Read Blocks": 28753,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Async Capable": false,
                  "Relation Name": "mytable",
                  "Schema": "public",
                  "Alias": "mytable",
                  "Startup Cost": 0,
                  "Total Cost": 47416.88,
                  "Plan Rows": 1,
                  "Plan Width": 30928,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 3.919,
                  "Actual Total Time": 59.222,
                  "Actual Rows": 1,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Output": [
                    "mytable.tin"
                  ],
                  "Filter": "(mytable.id = 1 )",
                  "Rows Removed by Filter": 200428,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 16155,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 28753,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Settings": {
      "search_path": "\"$user\", public, topology"
    },
    "Planning": {
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0
    },
    "Planning Time": 0.055,
    "Triggers": [],
    "Execution Time": 60.785
  }
]
```

##### Visual results

[image: visual results without st_tesselate]